# Accessibility: aria combobox with grid and grouping

Tags: html, combobox, accessibility, wai-aria

I have an existing (search autocomplete) component that needs to be made accessible.

The component consists of a text input, which on input opens a combobox (with data fetched from the server) which shows the data in a grid-like layout with additional information like categories and some visual styling (the icons are purely decoration and can probably be hidden from screen readers). To my understanding, this would be implemented according to [this example](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.2/examples/combobox/grid-combo.html).

However, the options in the combobox are also grouped by type (eg. "Content", "Categories"), which, in a combobox using a listbox, would be implemented using the 'group' role like in [this example](https://w3c.github.io/aria-practices/examples/listbox/listbox-grouped.html). I know this is an editor's draft, but in the spec it is already in the [working draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#listbox).

Now, is it possible to implement this in an accessible way, having both the grouping (ideally with the grouping semantic available to the screen reader, like with role='group') and the additional information (ideally in gridcells, as in the example)?

Or will I have to resort to hiding either of them, to either using a listbox and hiding the additional information from the screen reader, or by using a grid and having either no grouping or just rows that are non-interactive and have no semantic meaning?

[image: Screenshot of the content of the grid]

Note: I have no influence over the styling/layout, only what is presented to the screen reader. I am aware that this is not the most ideal starting point.

Comment: Could you drop your current HTML in a snippet. Support for `role="grid"` is poor and it may be a redesign of your HTML will make it accessible. `role="grid"` is basically "treat this data like a table" - at which point you should probably use a table anyway (but guessing at the moment as your screen shot doesn't quite paint the full picture). If there are full width rows like the picture I have no doubt this could be simplified.

Comment: I'd rather not add the current HTML, as it needs to be entirely reworked either way, currently it is not accessible at all. (And it is not my code). My question was what pattern best to use when rewriting it.

As I said, redesigning the layout is not an option, I can only make it accessible.
The screenshot should cover the most important parts - there can be more options, and more tags below these options (in one line), and more groups, but the screenshot covers all possible elements.

Is there a resource to check how well supported roles are?